# React CheckBox Content Display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*I am new to learning React and Javascript* I am building a form for practice. I want it to function where a user will be able to check a box, and subsequent unique content will then be displayed below. My issue is that I currently have it where I am able to select the boxes, but only one message {content} is displayed across all checkboxes. It also behaves in a manner in which with one box selected, the message is displayed. When two boxes are selected, the message disappears. With three boxes checked, the message appears again, and so on and so forth. I want each box to correspond to a unique message, and when multiple boxes are checked all content messages are displayed. Any tips on how to get this accomplished?

Here is my current code:

```
 render() {
    const content = this.state.checked ? (
      <div> Instructions Here </div>
    ) : null;

    return (
        <div className="mx-auto py-3 justify-content-center">
        <CheckboxGroup inline name="checkboxGroup1">
          <Checkbox type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } value={1}  > Google</Checkbox>
          <Checkbox type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } value={2}  > Slack</Checkbox>
          <Checkbox type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } value={3}  > Okta</Checkbox>
          <Checkbox type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } value={4}  > 1Password</Checkbox>
          <Checkbox type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange } value={5}  > OpenVPN</Checkbox>
        </CheckboxGroup>
        { content }
      </div>
```

I am using an CheckBox group with multiple check boxes. Each correponding back to the {content} item. But I would like the {content} item to change depending on which box is selected.